# How to access the Reports for OverageHighVolume Portal user license?

Tags: reporting, permissions, permission-sets

I need to access the Reports Folders in Portal Page, which the portal users are contains the **OverageHighVolume Portal user profile**. I was check it on the Profile Permissions the RunReport checkbox is not availbale for this profile. Is there any other way to view the Reports for this particular portal profile(Overage High Volume Portal)?